# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

In the module federation remote and host app configs attached below and its a react typescript applications.

A simple button component is used in the host app, able to see the component with default props but when I use the custom created **recharts** component not able to read the passed props in remote app but if we log the props it shows the data.

Remote

[image]

Host

[image]

Host App.tsx

Marked properties are optional, in button component i'm able to read and use the props key value but not able to use the props key value in BarChart component.
[image]

ERROR i'm getting

[image]

Any suggestion or solutions please do reply.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to ResponsiveContainer wrapper component.
I removed the wrapper component and tried it's working but I need different solution without removing the wrapper component.